# resharper 8.1 compatibility to StyleCop

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide, compatibility, stylecop, resharper-8.0

I have VS2013, and want to work with resharper and style cop together in the IDE (have all the notifications of style cop, all the quick fixes together)

installed Resharper 8.1
Installed latest StyleCop-4.7.49.0

Configured my .csproj to work with stylecop and have build errors and all (straight from StyleCop settings). Copied to the .sln folder the Settings.StyleCop file.

However - Resharper don't recognize it - no notifications within the code, no mentioning in Resharper > Tools,

How can I make them speak with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StyleCop 4.7.49 is not compatible with Resharper 8.1. The StyleCop - Resharper integration is not completely in sync with all the latest versions so to get full compatibility you need to run Resharper 8.2.

Specifically the version called:
ReSharper 8.2 (release date 2014-03-20)  http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharperSetup.8.2.0.2160.msi

Comment: ok I'll download that - you're saying that this resharper version will be in full sync with the mentioned stylecop version?

Comment: It is the only version of Resharper 8.2 currently listed as compatible with StyleCop 4.7 so I assume this will cover the integration parts. I am myself running a later Resharper release and when I install StyleCop I get a warning that my version is not compatible.